# Smooth square integrable function function whose derivative is not square integrable

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions, derivatives, continuity

Motivated by quantum mechanical definitions, I am looking for a function $f$ defined on the whole real line that is square integrable and smooth, but its derivative is not square integrable. Does such a function exist? I already found an example if $f$ is not required to be smooth: $f(x)=x^{-\frac{1}{3}}$ for $x \in [-1,1]$ and $0$ otherwise does the job. However, I am interested in finding a function, which is smooth and satisfies this property.

Comment: Something like $\sin(x^n)/(1+x^2)$ for sufficiently large $n$ should do the trick.

Comment: What do you mean by sufficiently large n? How could this be chosen?

Comment: Any $n \geq 3$ will give you a function $f_n$ which is square-integrable, but not $f_n'$. Take $n = 3$, and compute $f_3'$ to verify by yourself that $\int f_3^2 < \infty$ but $\int (f_3')^2 = +\infty$.

Comment: Is there a trick to show that $f_3$ is square integrable, without computing its integral? To me it seems $f_3$ can't be computed explicitly. However, I was thinking of trying to use that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{sin^2(x^3)}{(1+x^2)^2} dx\leq \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2}dx$ and the latter can be computed. Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the way to go.

Comment: And in fact you don't need the latter to be exactly solvable, only bounded... e.g., $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2}dx \le \int_{-1}^{1} dx + 2\int_{1}^{\infty} x^{-4}dx$ is sufficient.  Generally you just need the behavior at $\pm\infty$ to be going to zero fast enough, and the behavior at any singularities (not applicable for smooth functions) to be locally square-integrable.

Comment: How can I show about its derivative that it is  not bounded? I computed the derivative to be $f'(x)=\frac{3x^2(1+x^2)\cos(x^3) -2x\sin(x^3)}{(1+x^2)^2}$, but do not know how to proceed to compute the integral of its square to show it is infinity.

Comment: I was thinking to try to bound the integral somehow from above and from below by two integrals that can be shown to be divergent. but i do not know how to carry this out.